# Qtile: Make parse function for long texts like browsers

Tags: python, archlinux

I have the following problem.
The widget "WindowName" displays very long Browser names (ie "Stackoverflow | Questions | Ask -- Mozilla Firefox)
Is there a way to shorten this? I am aware that qtile comes with a parse function but it's default function doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function solved this issue, however if someone has a better implementation I would greatly appreciate it.

Add this function to your config.py file

```
def longNameParse(text): 
for string in ["Chromium", "Firefox"]: #Add any other apps that have long names here
    if string in text:
        text = string
    else:
        text = text
return text
```

And then when you call your Window Name widget, you use the function as an argument

```
widget.WindowName(parse_text=longNameParse)
```

That fixed it

Comment: you can also use a dictionary to "look up" nicer names for things too.